# Creating an ABPerson object

Tags: xcode, addressbook, vcf-vcard

This problem is almost certainly gonna have a really simple answer, but I just can't see it. I'm programming an app for the iPhone in Xcode and I'm trying to create an instance of an ABPerson object, but can't. In my .h file, I am importing as follows:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>
```

Then when I try to create it using "ABPerson *person;", it gives the error, "Unknown type name 'ABPerson'".

I have searched the internet and there doesn't seem to be much on the use of ABPerson and where I have seen it used, they have done it like this and its worked fine.

Ultimately, I want to create a VCard containing the details of somebody which the user can then save to their phone so if you know of another way of doing this which would eliminate this problem, that would also be great.

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the AddressBook framework to your app? Look in XCode4, look at your project file -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

Comment: Yeah thats all been added.I imported <AddressBook/AddressBook.h> and <AddressBook.ABPerson.h>

Comment: Just saw your code ... 2 things: a) there is no such thing as an ABPerson type; what you probably want is a ABRecordRef. b) Address book types are not Objective-C objects, so you can't create a pointer to them. This is probably what you want: "ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();"

Comment: Ok thanks, I now have an ABPerson created as you said above. I am now trying to initialise the ABPerson created with a VCardRepresentation using the "initWithVCardRepresentation" method but to no avail yet. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Although actually, when I try to run it now it fails. In my .h files I have

"ABRecordRef person"

then

"@property (nonatomic, assign) ABRecordRef person;"

Then in my .m file, I synthesise 'person' and initialise it

"person = ABPersonCreate();"

and it gives me the error

"symbol(s) not found for architecture i386"

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: OK, sorted this out now and it compiles again but I still haven't managed to get "initWithVCardRepresentation" working yet

Comment: You should frame that as a separate question. I don't have any experience with the initWithVCardRepresentation API. You should mark this answer for the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
```